# How can I resolve an env issue in React for API use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to request data from an an api and it throws me the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

Her's my code

```
  const getPopular = async () => {
   const api = await fetch (`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&number=9`)
   const data = await api.json();
   console.log(data);
  }
```

I've made sure that the env file is outside the `/src` folder, I've made sure the key is correct, I've restarted the server, I've made sure `REACT_APP_API_KEY` is correctly written, And also it works fine when I replace `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}` with the actual key. So what am I missing?

Comment: Are you using CRA or Vite?

Comment: @ivanatias I'm using Vite. Does it matter?

Comment: It does. In Vite you have to access the environment variables like: `import.meta.env.VITE_NAME`. Notice the `VITE` prefix, which is essentially the same as `REACT_APP` on CRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, env's are handled differently in Vite

```
  const getPopular = async () => {
    const api = await fetch (`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY}&number=9`)
    const data = await api.json();
    setPopular(data.recipes)
    console.log(data);
 }
```

And the variable in the `.env` file will be prefixed with `VITE_`
And that does the trick.

Credits to @ivanatias for the help